# Configure Google Nearby Notification API to use Facebook App Intent

Tags: facebook, beacon, google-nearby, proximityapi

Is it possible to pass Facebook's Android App intent while subscribing for Nearby Notification on Google Beacon Dashboard? I want to open my company's Facebook Page on the Facebook App when in proximity of the Beacon. In case it can be done, what should be passed in intent and scheme parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make this happen, you need to add a Nearby notification attachement url to your beacon.  You can read an overview of how to do this [here.](https://developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/attachment_data_format#app_with_web_fallback)

Here's an example of constructing a the url to attach to your beacon.  In order to go to a Facebook profile of Google, you can use a URL scheme to launch the native app like this:

```
fb://profile/Google
```

Since the native app (com.facebook.katana) may not be installed, Nearby allows you to specify a URL to launch in the browser if the app is not installed.  You can set up an app intent URL with a web fallback for use on Nearby like this:

```
intent://profile/Google#Intent;scheme=fb;package=com.facebook.katana; \
S.browser_fallback_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FGoogle%2F;end
```

See [here](https://developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/attachment_data_format#app_with_web_fallback) for more info on how to construct such URLs.

Comment: I am as of now trying with Beacon Dashboard. I used the following configuration: 'Intent scheme: fb Intent path: Profile/<PageName> Package: com.facebook.katana' and a corresponding Page URL. The app opens up but the particular page is not loaded. Web Fallback URL is also working fine. Did I do it correct? I also tried Intent path as Page/<PageName>.

Comment: Also, is there a way to generalize the values of intent scheme and path? As in, if I would want to open any Android App.

Comment: The intent scheme and the path are derived from the standard intent URL scheme.   So fb://profile/Google has the scheme of "fb" and the path of "/profile/Google"

Comment: Are you aware if the app intent URL with web fallback is not working with Nearby? I tried with normal app intent for my app and it's working fine. For the web fallback case, Nearby Notification shows up but nothing happens when I click on the notification for both the cases (app installed and app not installed). I then tried using the intent url you mentioned above for facebook and noticed the same issue. Nothing happens when I click on the notification. Is the web fallback disabled?